# Is memcpy() the most memory intensive job?

Tags: memcpy, workload

Thank you for your help in advance.

Recently I'm looking into `memcpy()`. I believe any workloads doing nothing but `memcpy()` must be the most memory-intensive(requiring high memory bandwidth) workloads. Is it true? Aren't there any workloads that require more bandwidth while conducting functions other than `memcpy()`?

There is a story I'm going over this issue. I used a simulator (MARSSx86) and ran `memcpy()` and other SPEC Benchmark (particularly SPEC OMP 12 for multi-thread workloads). No matter how many cores I virtually build, I manually allocated `memcpy()` on every single-core by Linux `taskset`, but the results show less bandwidth than the one generated by SPEC workloads. Therefore I'm confused.

Comment: It might depend upon your memcpy implementation, cpu and addresses of memory you are copying between.  For years compiler vendors used to recognize key benchmarks and generate special code for them; I wouldn't be surprised if CPU vendors are doing that now.  Either way, tickling the speculative fetcher may require a certain art, and is likely the key to maxing out the bus.   You can probably google a dozen memcpy's; why not try a few different ones and see what the numbers tell you.

Comment: Roger that. You mean trying different implementations of `memcpy()`, right? I have been using POSIX one.

Comment: Yes; that is a good start.